# JQuery mobile validation

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a mobile application in VS2010 using Jquery mobile and MVC4. Can you please advise me on how best to validate the textbox in the code segment below on submit? I only need to check that it contains a value. Ideally, I would like to put an error message just below this div.

```
<div data-theme="a" class="ui-grid-a">
     <div class="ui-block-a">@Html.TextBox("id", "", new { @class = "mystyleclass", onclick = "this.value=''" })</div>   
     <div class="ui-block-b">
          <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Search</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC, is this textbox connected to a model element? in that case add the [Required] tag above in in the model, make it an @html.texboxfor and then have a validationMessageFor beneath the html element.  If you are just checking that is isn't empty then do

```
<script>
$(":button").click(function(){
   if($("#id").val()!=""){
        //whatever you're trying to submit    
   }
   else{
       //show your error message
   }
});
</script>
```

in jQuery.  Also you should probably use id's on the button so you don't have to use the :button selector.

Comment: Hi, the textbox is not connected to the model. If needs be I could do so but I am a getting the value in the textbox from the form in the controller action.